# Apache poi ConditionalFormatting not working properly

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using apache poi to create excels in my java application.

My use case is when the value in **A1** is `Change it`.

Style in cells **A10** to **A14** will be changed.

For this I'm following feature of ConditionalFormatting provided by poi.

But the style is only getting applied to cell **A10** & not till **A14**.

What am I missing?

Code:

```
private void addValidations(Sheet sheet) {
    SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
    ConditionalFormattingRule rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("=A1=\"Change it\"");
    FontFormatting fontFmt = rule1.createFontFormatting();
    fontFmt.setFontStyle(true, false);
    fontFmt.setFontColorIndex(IndexedColors.YELLOW.index);
    BorderFormatting bordFmt = rule1.createBorderFormatting();
    bordFmt.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
    bordFmt.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THICK);
    bordFmt.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.DASHED);
    bordFmt.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.DOTTED);
    ConditionalFormattingRule [] cfRules =
            {
                    rule1
            };
    CellRangeAddress[] regions = {
            CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A10:A14")
    };
    sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, cfRules);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code `sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("=A1=\"Change it\"");` cannot work at all. In `HSSF` it throws `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: The specified formula '=A1="Change it"' starts with an equals sign which is not allowed.`. In `XSSF` it creates a corrupt `*.xlsx` file. The leading equals sign is not stored in `Excel` formula cells. t only is shown in `Excel`'s `GUI`. So it would must be `sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("A1=\"Change it\"");`.

And the formula `=A1="Change it"` is relative in column letter as well as in row number. So applied to cell `A10` it means `=A1="Change it"`. But applied to cell `A11` it means `=A2="Change it"`. And applied to cell `A12` it means `=A3="Change it"` and so on. So if the need is changing all font colors in `A10:A14` if content of `A1` changes, then the reference in the formula would must be fixed using `$`. So it would must be `sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("A$1=\"Change it\"");`.

Complete Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class ConditionalFormatting {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath ="./ConditionalFormatting.xlsx";
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); String filePath ="./ConditionalFormatting.xls";

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  for (int r = 9; r < 14; r++) {
   sheet.createRow(r).createCell(0).setCellValue("Text in Cell A" + (r+1));
  }

  SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();

  ConditionalFormattingRule rule = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("A$1=\"Change it\"");
  FontFormatting fontFormatting = rule.createFontFormatting();
  fontFormatting.setFontStyle(false, true);
  fontFormatting.setFontColorIndex(IndexedColors.YELLOW.index);

  ConditionalFormattingRule[] cfRules = new ConditionalFormattingRule[]{rule};

  CellRangeAddress[] regions = new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A10:A14")};

  sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, cfRules);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

This changes font color in `A10:A14` to yellow if cell content in `A1` is `Change it`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if this works.

```
CellRangeAddress[] regions = new CellRangeAddress[]{ CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A10:A14") };
```